# mysql loop through columns until null is found, then insert and break

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a mysql query that does the following....

I have a mySql table called 'devices' and a row in this table called 'row'. The 'row' has 15 columns that are initially null. I want to start on column 1 and check if null. If null, insert something into this column for 'row' and break the loop. if not null, move onto column 2 and repeat. What is the best way of achieving this?

### Schema below:

### -- Table structure for table `devices`

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `uid` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `d1` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d2` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d3` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d4` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d5` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d6` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d7` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d8` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d9` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d10` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d11` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d12` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d13` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d14` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `d15` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### --
-- Dumping data for table `devices`

```
INSERT INTO `devices` (`uid`, `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`, `d5`, `d6`, `d7`, `d8`, `d9`, `d10`, `d11`, `d12`, `d13`, `d14`, `d15`) VALUES
('t', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('tt', '0202020', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema of this table, please?

Comment: I am not sure how to find this on phpmyadmin?

Comment: You can click the Export tab on phpmyadmin and use that screen to save the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Also, is it better to iterate on the sql side as my question suggests or through the programming side, like php? I was thinking sql side is better for this. I know how to do the programming side.

Comment: Ok I added what I think you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that I hope someone has a cleaner solution to this problem, but here's how I would approach it.

I would declare a CURSOR to iterate through the rows of the `devices` table, unless you are always going to be dealing with just one row. If you do not know how to use cursors, please [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html).

Declare a variable for each column in your table and select the row data into those variables. Then I would use a CASE statement, like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN d1 IS NULL THEN UPDATE `devices` SET `d1` = 'value'; RETURN;
    WHEN d2 IS NULL THEN UPDATE `devices` SET `d2` = 'value'; RETURN; 
    (etc.)
    WHEN d15 IS NULL THEN UPDATE `devices` SET `d15` = 'value'; RETURN;
    ELSE RETURN;
END CASE
```

This solution is rather clunky, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I was looking for something more programmatic like a for loop. We can leave this up though, for the time being. Thank you. Also, I don't want to update every column that is null. I want to update the first column that is null and then break out of the statement completely, leaving the other columns still null.

Comment: This will break out of the CASE statement with the RETURN statement after each WHEN, so the first WHEN statement that is true will apply and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix your data model.  This is an *awful* data model.  But that is for another question:

Then, MySQL makes this confusing because it does not follow standard SQL in how to update columns.  So . . .

```
update t join
       (select t.uid,
               (case when d1 is null then 1
                     when d2 is null then 2
                     when d3 is null then 3
                     . . .
                end) as which
        from t
       ) tt
       using (uid)
    set d1 = (case when which = 1 then ? else d1 end),
        d2 = (case when which = 2 then ? else d2 end),
        . . .
    where t.uid = ?;
```

The subquery determines which column should be updated.  The `set` actually updates only that column.

Comment: Thanks. What data model do you suggest?

Comment: Each `d` value should be on its own row, along with an ordering column (which you seem to care about).

Comment: I decided to do this programatically since I will eventually be dealing with many more columns. I am not sure why you suggest to switch my columns to rows. I am adding rows to the database and it seems good. Basically every unit that is registered, will un-null the first column that is null but only for the given user, which is the row. Any ways, thanks for your input. I might post my answer as well.